# guard doesn't redirect on time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

The page is not redirecting correctly by "the guard" so the URL stay like this http://localhost:8100/ instead of http://localhost:8100/auth  so it display a blank page.

auth.guard.ts

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.authService.userIsAuthenticated) {
      console.log('route to /auth');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
    }
    console.log('CanLoad exit');
    return this.authService.userIsAuthenticated;
  }
```

auth.service.ts

```
  get userIsAuthenticated() {
    return this.user$.asObservable().pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('userIsAuthenticated', !!user.authtoken);
          return !!user.authtoken;
        } else {
          console.log('UserIsAuthenticated exit with false value');
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

So I did a tracing with console.log and I saw CanLoad doesn't wait for the UserIsAuthenticated return.

[image]

Thank for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!this.authService.userIsAuthenticated) {
```

You are checking if an Observable is truthy. It is truthy since it is an Observable. It doesn't check for the value of the Observable.

Try

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.userIsAuthenticated.pipe(
      tap(authenticated => if (!authenticated) { this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth') } )
    );
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't like the writing :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i forgot to tell you that i'm working with a BehaviorSubject.  user$ is a BehaviorSubject

Comment: Thanks so much @MoxxiManagarm. There is the correct code base on your advice:

Comment: ```  canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.userIsAuthenticated.pipe(
      take(1), tap(authenticated => {if (!authenticated) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
      }
    })
    );
  }```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was just need to invalid in the auth.guard.ts

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.authService.userIsAuthenticated || 'invalid') {
      console.log('route to /auth');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
    }
    console.log('CanLoad exit');
    return this.authService.userIsAuthenticated;
  }
```

Comment: yes you're right, this solution doesn't work. My bad